# Precise statement of Number Avoidance Theorem in game theory

Tags: proof-explanation, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

**Background:** In the book *Winning Ways for Your Mathematical Plays* on combinatorial game theory, the Number Avoidance Theorem is stated:

> DON'T MOVE IN A NUMBER UNLESS THERE'S NOTHING ELSE TO DO!

(sic.) The idea is that a move in a number guarantees a strictly worsened position for yourself. In the formal proof, they start:

> It will be enough to prove that if $x$ is equal to a number, but $G$ is not, and if
> $$
> G+x\mathop{\vert\triangleright}0, \quad \textrm{then some} \quad G^L+x\ge0.
> $$

**My question:** How should the theorem be precisely interpreted? My first interpretation was

> (1) There is a move $G^L$ such that $G^L+x\ge G+x^L$.

Or might it be the (a priori) weaker statement

> (2) If the moving player is winning in $G + x$, then there is a winning move from $G$.

(2) would mean that the player never misses out on a win by not playing in the number, but perhaps it might not be the "cleanest" win possible (i.e. with the highest values throughout). The reason for my confusion is that the given proof seems to prove (2), even though I thought (1) was the natural interpretation. So is (1) false, or are (1) and (2) in fact equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that these statements are not a priori equivalent.  In fact, for long games, they are distinct.  Let's consider the following statements, where $x$ is a number and $G$ is a non-number.

- (A) If $G + x ⧐ 0$ then some $G^L + x \ge 0$.
- (B) $G + x = \{G^L + x \mid G^R + x\}$.
- (1) For any $x^L$ there is a move $G^L$ such that $G^L + x \ge G + x^L$.
- (2) If the moving player is winning in $G + x$ then there is a winning move from $G$.

If we consider these statements applied to both $G$ and $-G$ simultaneously, then we have the implications
$$(1) \implies (\text{B}) \implies (\text{A}) \Longleftrightarrow (2)$$

(A) holds for all games, even long ones; the proof is as follows.<sup>1</sup>  Since $G + x ⧐ 0$ then either some $G^L + x \ge 0$ in which case we are done, or some $G + x^L \ge 0$.  Let $y$ be a simplest number such that $y \le x$ and $G + y \ge 0$.  (We know such a $y$ exists since $x^L$ satisfies these conditions.)  Since $G$ is not a number, in fact $G + y > 0$.  Thus either some $G^L + y \ge 0$ or $G + y^L \ge 0$; but the latter contradicts the simplesticity of $y$.  In the former case we have $G^L + x \ge G^L + y \ge 0$.

(1) is true for short games; this can be shown by analyzing the left and right stops.<sup>2</sup>  However, (B) is false for certain long games.  Conway<sup>3</sup> gives the example of $G = \{\mathbb{R}|\mathbb{R}\}$.   In this case we have $\{G^L + x \mid G^R + x\} = G$ for any real number $x$, and so (B) becomes $G + x = G$ which is absurd for nonzero $x$.

I am not certain whether (B) implies (1); I think it does but it isn't obvious.

<sup>1</sup> This is essentially the proof from *Winning Ways*, adapted slightly to apply to long games.

<sup>2</sup> *Lessons in Play: An Introduction to Combinatorial Game Theory*, Theorem 6.12.

<sup>3</sup> *On Numbers and Games*, Chapter 16.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think this question would be dug up; thanks! It's been a good while since I thought about game theory, so I have a few questions IYDM. 1. Does short/long games mean games of (in)finite length, or something similar? 2. For trying to understand why $(1)\implies (B)$, is it correct that, if $G\ge H$, then $\{G,H\mid K\} = \{G, K\}$? Also, the reason you consider $-G$ is to get the corresponding argument for the right player moves?

Comment: @Milten 1. Yes. A short game is a game $G$ whose birthday is a finite natural number $k$.  This means that if Left and Right play some moves in $G$, then no matter which order they play moves in, at most $k$ moves can be made in total.  2. Yes, this is correct but you have a typo ($\{G \mid K\}$ rather than $\{G, K\}$).  3. Yes, exactly.